# Weblogic 12.2.1.3.0 REST service with sub-resource and generics

Tags: java, rest, jersey, wildfly, weblogic12c

I have the following simple classes for my REST application:

```java
public class BaseDTO {
    private long id;
    private String name;

    // setters and getters
}

@XmlRootElement
public class SimpleDTO extends BaseDTO {
    private String description;

    // setters and getters
}

public class SimplePojo extends BasePojo {
    private String description;

    public abstract class BaseResource<DTO, POJO> {

        @POST
        @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        public Response create(DTO payload) {
            POJO pojo = this.getPojoFromDto(payload);
            return Response.ok(pojo).build();
        }

    public abstract POJO getPojoFromDto(DTO dto);
}

@ApplicationScoped
public class SimpleResource extends BaseResource<SimpleDTO, SimplePojo> {

    @Override
    public SimplePojo getPojoFromDto(SimpleDTO dto) {
        SimplePojo pojo = new SimplePojo();
        pojo.setId(dto.getId());
        pojo.setName(dto.getName());
        pojo.setDescription(dto.getDescription());

        return pojo;
    }
}

@Dependent
@Path("/models")
public class SimpleModelResource {

    @Inject
    private Instance<Object> subResource;

    @Path("/{model-id:[0-9]+}")
    public SimpleRouterResource getModel() {
        return subResource.select(SimpleRouterResource.class).get();
    }
}

@ApplicationPath("/api")
public class RestApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<>();
        classes.add(SimpleModelResource.class);
        return classes;
    }
}
```

### WildFly 8.2.1.Final OK

If I deploy the application under WildFly 8.2.1.Final everything works fine, I can shot the post request `localhost:8080/web-app/api/models/9/simple` and the method `getPojoFromDto` is called, the POJO is created and returned.

WildFly uses Jackson 2.4.1.

### Weblogic 12.2.1.3.0 KO

If I deploy under Weblogic 12c it does not work, it produces a `ClassCastException`.

```
]] Root cause of ServletException.
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to 
com.dummyprojects.model.SimpleDTO
    at 
com.dummyprojects.rest.SimpleResource.getPojoFromDto(SimpleResource.java:8)
    at com.dummyprojects.rest.BaseResource.create(BaseResource.java:19)
    at   
 com.dummyprojects.rest.SimpleResource$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.create(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at 
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
```

**Note!** I have disable MOXy in favor or Jackson, the one provided by Weblogic so version 2.4.5.

#### What I have tried

- put in the `WEB-INF\lib` Jackson 2.9.2 and reference from `weblogic.xml`

I guess the issue is something related to `jersey` but I am not sure.

[image]

Do you have any suggestion or already found this problem?

Thanks a lot in advance

#### Update 1

I have added some restrictions

```
public abstract class BaseResource<DTO extends BaseDTO, POJO extends BasePojo> {...}
```

the exception now, as I expected, is

```
]] Root cause of ServletException.
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.dummyprojects.model.BaseDTO cannot be cast 
to com.dummyprojects.model.SimpleDTO
```

#### Update 2 (Solution)

```
public abstract class BaseResource<DTO extends BaseDTO, POJO extends BasePojo> {

    protected final Class<DTO> dtoType; // resolved in the constructor

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response create(InputStream payload, @Context Providers providers) throws IOException {
        DTO simpleDTO = (DTO)providers.getMessageBodyReader(dtoType, dtoType, new Annotation[0], MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
            .readFrom(dtoType, dtoType, new Annotation[0], MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE, new MultivaluedHashMap<>(), payload);


        POJO pojo = this.getPojoFromDto(simpleDTO);
        return Response.ok(pojo).build();
    }

    public abstract POJO getPojoFromDto(DTO dto);
}
```

So the issue is that the object injected by `weld` has still the basic type `BaseDTO` instead of the type of the subclass `SimpleDTO`. I suspect an issue in `jersey` or `weld`.

The workaround is to pass the good type to `Jackson` to get the `JSON` correctly unmarshalled.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Sounds strange but tag SimpleDTO  with @XmlElement

Comment: @Optional sorry I have forgotten to put the annotation but it was there and nothing has changed.

Comment: I am trying your sample.  Can you share SimplePojo or shall I just create a dummy SimplePojo like SimpleDTO? Also SimpleRouterResource  is missing. Can I just use your SimpleResource?

Comment: I tried with dummy classes but didn't see any exception.

Comment: @OptionaI have added the missing class, then I will post a new debug trace to show what is going on.